# GLSL compile error "memory exhausted"

Tags: memory, compiler-errors, glsl, shader

I am trying to implement a GLSL fragment shader with a complex if-else decision tree. Unfortunately the shader compiler fails quite early with a "syntax error - memory exhausted" error. Are there any constraints about the code size or decision tree depth in GLSL? Any suggestion how to overcome this issue?

```
bool block1(float p[16], float cb, float c_b) { 
  if(p[6] > cb)
   if(p[7] > cb)
    if(p[8] > cb)
     return true;
    else
     if(p[15] > cb)
      return true;
     else
      return false;
   else if(p[7] < c_b)
    if(p[14] > cb)
     if(p[15] > cb)
      return true;
     else
      return false;
    else if(p[14] < c_b)
     if(p[8] < c_b)
      if(p[9] < c_b)
       if(p[10] < c_b)
        if(p[11] < c_b)
         if(p[12] < c_b)
          if(p[13] < c_b)
           if(p[15] < c_b)
            return true;
           else
            return false;   // ';' : syntax error memory exhausted
          else
           return false;
         else
          return false;
        else
         return false;
       else
        return false;
      else
       return false;
     else
      return false;
    else
     return false;
   else
    if(p[14] > cb)
     if(p[15] > cb)
      return true;
     else
      return false;
    else
     return false;
  else if(p[6] < c_b)
   if(p[15] > cb)
    if(p[13] > cb)
     if(p[14] > cb)
      return true;
     else
      return false;
    else if(p[13] < c_b)
     if(p[7] < c_b)
      if(p[8] < c_b)
       if(p[9] < c_b)
        if(p[10] < c_b)
         if(p[11] < c_b)
          if(p[12] < c_b)
           if(p[14] < c_b)
            return true;
           else
            return false;
          else
           return false;
         else
          return false;
        else
         return false;
       else
        return false;
      else
       return false;
     else
      return false;
    else
     return false;
   else
    if(p[7] < c_b)
     if(p[8] < c_b)
      if(p[9] < c_b)
       if(p[10] < c_b)
        if(p[11] < c_b)
         if(p[12] < c_b)
          if(p[13] < c_b)
           if(p[14] < c_b)
            return true;
           else
            return false;
          else
           return false;
         else
          return false;
        else
         return false;
       else
        return false;
      else
       return false;
     else
      return false;
    else
     return false;
  else
   if(p[13] > cb)
    if(p[14] > cb)
     if(p[15] > cb)
      return true;
     else
      return false;
    else
     return false;
   else if(p[13] < c_b)
    if(p[7] < c_b)
     if(p[8] < c_b)
      if(p[9] < c_b)
       if(p[10] < c_b)
        if(p[11] < c_b)
         if(p[12] < c_b)
          if(p[14] < c_b)
           if(p[15] < c_b)
            return true;
           else
            return false;
          else
           return false;
         else
          return false;
        else
         return false;
       else
        return false;
      else
       return false;
     else
      return false;
    else
     return false;
   else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "*the shader compiler crashes quite early with a "syntax error - memory exhausted" error*" Do you get an error, or does it crash? Crashing and compiler errors aren't the same thing.

Comment: Sure, thanks for refinement. So, the compiler fails with that error.

Comment: In general, when you have written a fifth nested `if` statement, in pretty much *any language*, you should stop yourself and ask a very simple question: "Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?" Do not proceed to write that statement unless you have exhausted all other options. Or failing that, explain what this code is supposed to be trying to do, so that someone else can find a way that *doesn't* involve dozens of nested `if` statements.

Comment: Practically it's a boolean function with 16 inputs with a domain of 3 possible valise (as I can map each element of the p array to the one of the [0;c_b), [c_b;cb), [cb;inf) intervals). Said that, the function has 3^16 possible inputs so the truth table is rather big. The code above evaluates at most 32 inequality to determine the value of the function. Could you show me a more compact description of the same function that does not use unnecessary evaluations?

Comment: To all: before downvoting my question please could you try to answer it? I did not write the code above because I think it's a nice programming stile but because I could not come up with a solution with the same efficiency that is more compact (see my previous comment).

Comment: @MrTJ the question that comes to my mind is not whether wrote this code _for fun_, but rather, whether you wrote it. If you did, rewriting it as a logic expressions should be trivial. And more fun. Have at it! (I have a suspicion this was generated, and in the generation step all useful _explicit_ information was lost. I'm not about to recover it for you. Also, the size of the truth table doesn't matter. As is obvious from your code it is expressible using a limited set of conditions. Finally, the function _really_ doesn't take 16 floats, it only uses 6-15.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here, as I know nothing about shader languages.

### 1. Use logic combinations (and, or)

However I know general logic and lots of programming languages. Chances are BIG that a construct like:

```
if(p[8] < c_b)
 if(p[9] < c_b)
  if(p[10] < c_b)
   if(p[11] < c_b)
    if(p[12] < c_b)
     if(p[13] < c_b)
      if(p[15] < c_b)
       return true;
      else
       return false;   // ';' : syntax error memory exhausted
     else
      return false;
    else
     return false;
   else
    return false;
  else
   return false;
 else
  return false;
else
 return false;
```

Could trivially be stated equivalently as the following (single) boolean expression:

```
return (p[8] < c_b)
    && (p[9] < c_b)
    && (p[10] < c_b)
    && (p[11] < c_b)
    && (p[12] < c_b)
    && (p[13] < c_b)
    && (p[15] < c_b);
```

You might have to use `and` instead of `&&` depending on the exact grammar of the particular language.

### 2. Eliminate redundancy

I noticed at least two of the 'subtrees' are completely identical. More specifically, e.g. line #57 (formatting condensed for convenience, here):

```
    if(p[13] < c_b) if(p[7] < c_b) if(p[8] < c_b) if(p[9] < c_b) if(p[10] < c_b) if(p[11] < c_b) if(p[12] < c_b) if(p[14] < c_b)
        return true;
    else return false; else return false; else return false; else return false; else return false; else return false; else return false; else return false;
```

is completely identical to line #83

```
   if(p[7] < c_b) if(p[8] < c_b) if(p[9] < c_b) if(p[10] < c_b) if(p[11] < c_b) if(p[12] < c_b) if(p[13] < c_b) if(p[14] < c_b)
       return true;
   else return false; else return false; else return false; else return false; else return false; else return false; else return false; else
```

just with the `(p[13] < c_b)` condition moved nearer to the end. It is highly likely you could combine the branches in which this occurs.

**Instead of manually doing this (painstaking) process, I suggest making a truth table (just map out all possible inputs) and deducing a single boolean expression to generate the result value from that.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. Could you please reflect to my last comment to the original question?

Comment: I've [reflected on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828966/glsl-compile-error-memory-exhausted/15829150?noredirect=1#comment22524644_15828966) :)